# Calendario, no reservar si fecha ya esta ocupada

Tags: php

Buen día,

actualmente estoy atorado con un calendario que se basa en `php` y `mysql`

el calendario ya reserva y funciona correctamente, sin embargo estoy tratando de añadir que no me duplique las citas en fechas ya reservadas (tengo que comparar la fecha de inicio y la fecha final)

estoy tratando de hacer un select con los parámetros de la fecha y los horarios nuevos que estoy metiendo, si me devuelve un registro entonces significa que ya esta ocupado y no se puede insertar el nuevo registro, pero no me a funcionado me manda error y la verdad no se como decirle que me revise entre fecha inicial y fecha final, esto es lo que llevo

```
$consulta="select * from eventos where inicio=".$inicio_normal; 
$resultado=mysqli_query($consulta) or die (mysqli_error()); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0)     
    echo "lo sentimos, ya existe una reservacion en ese horario."; 


// insertamos el evento
$query="INSERT INTO eventos VALUES(null,'$titulo','$body','','$clase','$inicio','$final','$inicio_normal','$final_normal')";
```

Espero alguien me pueda resolver mi duda.

Gracias de antemano

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, añade a tu pregunta un ejemplo de un caso concreto que ilustre lo que pretendes obtener :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: yo creo una reservación el día 25 de marzo de 10 am a 4 pm y después alguien quiere reservar el mismo día pero a la 1 pm no me deje hacerlo porque la sala ya está ocupada en ese intervalo de tiempo, el link del compañero gbianchi si me a ayudado bastante a resolver dudas pero no logro que el codigo me funcione, realize o siguiente
$resultado= "SELECT *
    FROM eventos, 
    WHERE start >= end
      AND end <= start"
   
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)   

echo "lo sentimos, ya existe una reservacion en ese horario.";  
error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)